# How to enable Groupbox if the confirmation is equal to the database

Tags: vb.net

How to enable Groupbox if the confirmation is equal to the database?

I have txtpass.text which will be input for confirmation, if the the value in txtpass is equal to my database the groupbox will now enable. Is there something wrong in my code?

This is my code:

```
Private Sub txtpass_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles txtpass.KeyPress
    disconnect()
    connect()

    cmd = New Odbc.OdbcCommand("SELECT pass FROM secure", con)
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader

    If dr.Read AndAlso dr("pass").ToString = txtpass.Text Then
        gbscanpnum.Enabled = False
        gbscanpnum.Focus()
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use parameters to avoid SQL Injection.

```
cmd = New Odbc.OdbcCommand("SELECT * FROM secure WHERE pass=@pass", con)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", txtpass.Text.Trim)
```

For your code, Read just sets the cursor position of the reader, you still have to read the individual field.

```
If dr.Read AndAlso dr("pass").ToString = txtpass.Text Then
    gbscanpnum.Enabled = True
End If
```

or if receiving one or more rows means it worked, then just:

```
gbscanpnum.Enabled = dr.HasRows
```

If expecting one row and one column, [ExecuteScalar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) would work, too.

Your method is called `txtfeedernum_Enter` but it is being handled by the `txtpass.VisibleChanged` event.  That's kind-of messed up.  I'm guessing you should have a button and its click event handle this authentication.

Comment: Private Sub txtfeedernum_Enter(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles txtpass.VisibleChanged How about my declaration is this correct?

Comment: @RomJoy Why are you using the VisibleChanged event?  It's hard to see why you would call your code in that event.  I would think a button click event or something of that nature would be more appropriate.

Comment: Yes I know, but my client want is, if the txtpass is changed and if it is equal to my database it will now enable otherwise it will back to unabled.

Comment: @RomJoy But the VisibleChanged event is for when the control's visibility changes.  The name of your procedure is txtfeedernum_Enter but it is being handled by the VisibleChanged event (look at the "Handles" part of the line.  I'm guessing you originally meant to use the Enter event.

Comment: So what is your suggestion? Change my txtfeedernum_Enter to visible changed?

Comment: Or I would go for keypress?

Comment: @RomJoy I don't know.  Maybe have a button that says "Login" or something.  Use the click event.  If successful, hide the button, too.

Comment: Sir can you take a look my rvised code, I think a have a few problem now and I am near to my goal.

Comment: @RomJoy Ugh.  StackOverflow doesn't like to have the question be such a moving target.  By using the KeyPress event, your code will now run every time a character key is pressed.

Comment: Ahh ok, my code is now running. Thanks for the help.